# Merge common rows in PDF using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I am New to XSL. I have an XML file and I am using XSL to Generate pdf from it. I am able to display the  below table in PDF using Fo, FO block,

[image]

This generates the table perfectly with all data in different rows.

However, I need to display the Below format with merging

[image]

Below is the xml  and The XSL code I have Tried:

**XML**

```
"<DocumentElement>
  <Student>
    <Roll>1</Roll>
    <NAME>Mark</NAME>
    <Subject>1000502</Subject>
    <DESCRIPTION>Test_2046_1</DESCRIPTION>
    <Total>20</Total>
  </Student>
  <Student>
    <Roll>1</Roll>
    <NAME>Mark</NAME>
    <Subject>1117697</Subject>
    <DESCRIPTION>Test_2046_2</DESCRIPTION>
    <Total>20</Total>
  </Student>
  <Student>
    <Roll>2</Roll>
    <NAME>Henry</NAME>
    <Subject>1271267</Subject>
    <DESCRIPTION>Test_2046_3</DESCRIPTION>
    <Total>20</Total>
  </Student>
  <Student>
    <Roll>2</Roll>
    <NAME>Henry</NAME>
    <Subject>5013025</Subject>
    <Total>20</Total>
  </Student>
</DocumentElement>"
```

**XSL**

```
"<xsl:template match="DocumentElement">
    <fo:block break-before="page">
      <fo:table xsl:use-attribute-sets="data_table">
        <xsl:call-template name="StudentItemsHeading"/>
        <fo:table-body>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="Student"/>
        </fo:table-body>
      </fo:table>
    </fo:block>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="StudentItemsHeading">
    <fo:table-header>
      <fo:table-row xsl:use-attribute-sets="table_headers">
        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="bordered">
          <fo:block>Student ID#</fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="bordered">
          <fo:block>Student Name</fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="bordered">
          <fo:block>Subjects</fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="bordered">
          <fo:block>Subject Description</fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="bordered">
          <fo:block>Total Marks</fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="bordered">
          <fo:block>Min.</fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="bordered">
          <fo:block>Max.</fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
      </fo:table-row>
    </fo:table-header>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Student">
    <fo:table-row>
      <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="bordered">
        <fo:block white-space-collapse="false" xsl:use-attribute-sets="bold">
          <xsl:value-of select="Roll"/>
        </fo:block>
      </fo:table-cell>
      <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="bordered">
        <fo:block>
          <xsl:value-of select="NAME"/>
        </fo:block>
      </fo:table-cell>
      <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="bordered">
        <fo:block white-space-collapse="false" xsl:use-attribute-sets="bold">
          <xsl:value-of select="Subject"/>
        </fo:block>
      </fo:table-cell>
      <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="bordered">
        <fo:block white-space-collapse="false" xsl:use-attribute-sets="bold">
          <xsl:value-of select="DESCRIPTION"/>
        </fo:block>
      </fo:table-cell>
      <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="number_format bordered">
        <fo:block>
          <xsl:value-of select="Total"/>
        </fo:block>
      </fo:table-cell>
      <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="number_format bordered">
        <fo:block>
        </fo:block>
      </fo:table-cell>
      <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="number_format bordered">
        <fo:block>
        </fo:block>
      </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
  </xsl:template>
```

Please Help on how to Achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="Student"/>
```

use

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="Student" group-by="Roll">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

then in the template for `Student` use e.g.

```
  <xsl:template match="Student">
    <fo:table-row>
      <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
       <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="bordered" number-rows-spanned="{count(current-group())}">
        <fo:block white-space-collapse="false" xsl:use-attribute-sets="bold">
          <xsl:value-of select="Roll"/>
        </fo:block>
       </fo:table-cell>
       <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="bordered" number-rows-spanned="{count(current-group())}">
        <fo:block>
          <xsl:value-of select="NAME"/>
        </fo:block>
       </fo:table-cell>
      </xsl:if>
      <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="bordered">
        <fo:block white-space-collapse="false" xsl:use-attribute-sets="bold">
          <xsl:value-of select="Subject"/>
        </fo:block>
      </fo:table-cell>
      <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="bordered">
        <fo:block white-space-collapse="false" xsl:use-attribute-sets="bold">
          <xsl:value-of select="DESCRIPTION"/>
        </fo:block>
      </fo:table-cell>
      <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
       <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="number_format bordered" number-rows-spanned="{count(current-group())}">
        <fo:block>
          <xsl:value-of select="Total"/>
        </fo:block>
       </fo:table-cell>
      </xsl:if>
      <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="number_format bordered">
        <fo:block>
        </fo:block>
      </fo:table-cell>
      <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="number_format bordered">
        <fo:block>
        </fo:block>
      </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
  </xsl:template>
```

That assumes using XSLT 2 or 3 with e.g. Saxon 9 or 10.

Comment: I tried your above solution but I am getting an error : 'xsl:for-each-group' cannot be a child of the 'fo:table-body' element.

Comment: @Avinash, do you use Saxon 9 or 10 for XSLT? Which tool gives that error and is it perhaps only a warning or overzealous error of a schema based validator not prepared to deal with XSLT 2 or 3?